# Problem linking React Web App to online MongoDB Database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

It's supposed to add data when I click the register button on the register page. This is the code, is something wrong with it?

Index.js:

```
` const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');
    const User = require("./models/User")
    const bcrypt = require("bcrypt.js")
    const app = express();

    const salt = "yguhijomkpet";

    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());

    mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://hemendprincess:    <password>@cluster0.vd7walf.mongodb.net/Cluster0?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

    app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const {username, password} = req.body;
    try {
        const UserDoc = await User.create({
            username,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
        });
        res.json(UserDoc);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).json(e)
    }
   
    })

    app.listen(4000);`
```

RegisterPage.js:

```
`import { useState } from "react";

    export default function RegisterPage(){
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    async function register(ev){`
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/register", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
           ` });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Failed to register");
            }

            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data); // Log the response data

            // Additional logic after successful registration
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Registration error:", error.message);
        }
    } 
    return (
        <form className="register" onSubmit={register}>
            <h1>Register</h1>`
    `        <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Your Username" 
                value={username} 
                onChange={ev => setUsername(ev.target.value)} />
            <input 
                type="password" 
                placeholder="Your Password"
                value={password} 
                onChange={ev => setPassword(ev.target.value)}/>
            <button>Register</button>
        </form>
    );
    }  `
```

My concern is that nothing is showing in the MongoDB database when I input username and password and click "register" and even when i inspect the page in Edge or Chrome, it's showing me "JavaScript not enabled" when I have clearly enabled it.